# Cannot ping elastix phone system through openvpn

Tags: centos, openvpn

I setup openvpn on CentOs for our office. I'm using it without any problem, can ping all PCs and servers, network printers.

Recently I installed Elastix Phone System to our office, it's in the same IP range and I can ping Elastix server and open it's web interface within office network but not through openvpn.

It's strange that I can still ping all PCs, servers, printers even the network phones that are connected to Elastix but can't ping Elastix itself through openvpn

I checked the firewall on Elastix, it's all turned off. I even tried to turn it on and allow openvpn port but still no luck.

Does anyone happen to have same or similar issue or can guess what might be the problem?

Thanks

Edit:
Here is the route table.

```
172.21.17.8     *               255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth2
192.168.123.0   *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
default         172.21.17.14    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth2
```

Comment: If you do a traceroute, where does the failure happen?  From the Elastix box can you do a traceroute to an OpenVPN client?

Comment: Ok I did that, elastix has eth2 is for sip trunk, and eth0 is connected to local network. Even though dns and gateway is correct on eth0, tracert tries to exit from eth2 and cannot reach internet, and cannot ping google or other IPs, but local works. It tries to exit using eth2, not eth0, why?

Comment: I would probably guess that you have tried to assign multiple gateways, or you have bad routes setup on that machine.  Can you show us the route table?

Comment: Ok I put route table into the question

Answer (score 0):

The route table on your Elastix is probably wrong.  If packets from the OpenVPN network are coming via eth0, and your OpenVPN is using a routed setup, then the OpenVPN clients are not on your `192.168.123.0 /24` subnet.

The answer might be as simple as adding a route on your Elastix box for the subnet used by the OpenVPN server.

To temporarily add a route use a command like `/bin/ip route add 192.168.125.0/24 via 192.168.123.254` as in `/bin/ip route add network/bits via gateway`.   If don't have any other routers, then use your OpenVPN box as the gateway.